# Translate bash command to xonsh

Tags: bash, xonsh

I have a .sh script i used which is no longer working. It checks if a Docker container exists by:

```
if [ -z "$(docker ps -q -a -f name=mujoco_roboy)" ]
```

This does not work in xonsh.

`(docker ps -q -a -f name=mujoco_roboy)` delivers some console output. How can i continue from that?

https://xon.sh/bash_to_xsh.html

Comment: Whoever voted to close, please retract your votes. This is a perfectly valid question about another Linux shell (Xonsh).

Answer (score 0):

Xonsh uses a Python (not Bash) syntax, so an if statement is constructed in another way (unfortunately I'm not a Python expert).

But the basic structure is like this:

```
a = 200
b = 33
if b > a:
    print("b is greater than a")
elif a == b:
    print("a and b are equal")
else:
    print("a is greater than b")
```

Remember, in Python, the indentation is important and part of the language, instead of closing words in Bash (`fi`).

I found this [Python reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp), which hopefully can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
 I code in python, this is also why I wanted to get xonsh in the first place
But i do not know how to execute this in python. 

(docker ps -q -a -f name=mujoco_roboy) is a console command that asks docker for an output. I'd someho have to catch that and evaluate it.

Comment: Hmm I see. So actually this is about evaluating an expression, and not the if statement itself..